# what does "all" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> Probably not. Bombing is measured in tons, not bombs. There are **all** different sizes of bombs, but what matters in a strategic bombing campaign is the total number of tons dropped.

What does "all" mean?

Answer (score 2):

"All different" is an idiomatic phrase meaning 'many different'.

Answer (score 1):

It describes the wide variety or range of sizes of bombs there are.